# Javascript/jQuery - Kepler Orbit with inadvertent acceleration

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I have been working to implement a simple Kepler Orbit in a proof of concept I am working on in JavaScript. The problem I am facing is that the math I have to use causes a degree of inaccuracy in the generated points. I am using the following equation to determine my coordinates.

`y = sqrt(r-x^2)`

I use a linearly increasing X value to determine my y coordinate which (when it approaches the upper limit of `X`) causes the Y value to become large quickly. When I try to animate anything along the coordinates I receive, it accelerates towards the limits of my equation.

Currently I am only calculating Quadrant II in my cartesian plane and I am sure there is a much better way to do this, however I am fairly new to JavaScript math methods and am not entirely sure how to implement what I am trying to do.

I am wondering if polar coordinates may be the way to go for calculation, and then converting to cartesian using the function `r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` with the known `x,y` coords if possible.

Like I said I am not entirely sure how to accomplish this or if it is possible. Below is the source to what I have so far. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
    var x = 0;
    var y;
    var r = 10;
    var check = setInterval(function(){topHalf()}, 20);

    function topHalf(){
    if (Math.pow(x,2) <= 10){

            y = Math.sqrt(r-(Math.pow(x,2)));   
            x = x + 0.01;
            $('#orb').offset({top:y*100, left:x*100});



    }else{
        console.log('done');
        clearInterval(check);
    }


    }
```

Comment: I think is ...'causes the Y value to become SMALL quickly'...

Comment: There's no reason to use `Math.pow()` when you just want to square a value. Use `x * x`.

Comment: NB: `setInterval(function() { f() }, 20)` should just be `setInterval(f, 20)`

Comment: the reason I use an anonymous function to call my function, is because it calls the function immediately even though I am declaring the setInterval in a variable. Calling it in a variable allows me to clear the interval, so it is needed. This is exactly how they do it on the w3schools site.

I realize that Math.pow() wasn't needed, but I was using it from a different project where I did a similar calculation, but with a higher exponent.

Y becomes small quickly, that is the problem. I am wondering if there is a better way to calculate Y, as I would like the points to be roughly the same.

Answer (score 0):

This instruction is not precise in floating point (since 0.01 cannot be represented as an exact number). The error becomes bigger at every iteration.

```
x = x + 0.01;
```

replace with

```
i = i + 1
x = i * 0.01
```

The error is further amplified by the square root, and possibly by the Pow. Replace all Math.pow(x,2) with x * x

Comment: It seems that the reason Y becomes small so quickly is because of the nature of the function. It is an exponential function, which means as it approaches it's limits, it speeds up.

I just tested the ratio of one Y value to the next and it starts out near 1, and after thousands of iterations, ends at .46 . It stays around 1 for most of the calculations, and when it approaches y=0, it really accelerates. So I have to find out 1 of 2 things, either a value to multiply x by, that will scale the ratio at the same rate, or the total distance, and run a different function to traverse the length.

Comment: OK. In ephemeris software I usually see polar coordinates. In orbit software simulations I usualle see vectors (2D or 3D), simulating mass, acceleration and speed.

Comment: Indeed, I was missing a lot of information. I was just trying to get some sort of rotational animation from this. I have since updated the code with vectors for distance, mass, acceleration based on distance vectors, and speed based on all the above. I appreciate the input, I guess I just needed to do some more research. Everything works great now, including elliptical orbits, just working on matrix rotations now. Thanks again.